# Water on the inside of corner

Tags: water, siding, aluminum

My secobd floor sticks out over my frist floor. I have aluminum siding on the second floor.  I noticed water was coming in and down the corner piece.  Its on the inside behind the j channel. [image]
The red arrow shows were it is wet.

[image]

Is it more likely water is coming in from the top or do you think its coming in from. The side and somehow working its way around the j channel

Comment: You did the best you could with your arrow, but it's still hard to tell exactly where it's pointing. Is the water inside the corner piece, between the corner piece and the J-channel, or within the "J" of the J-channel between it and the siding?

Comment: Its on the inside of the corner piece. If I stick my finger in the big hole it feels wet on the inside.

Comment: Unless you find some damage - a hole in the corner piece or the J-channel further up, I'd think it's coming from the top. Before lobbing a huge wad of silicone sealant around the top of the corner piece, I'd investigate the top to see if there are signs of water ingress up there - is it somehow dripping in from the soffit or gutter above?